# Fonts and Color style for C# / Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How to customize fonts color for c# language in visual studio 2012 ?
In text editor settings only c/c++ ,XAML,SQL items are visible.

Comment: http://studiostyl.es/

Comment: @Steve I know this website but how to manage it from visual texteditor settings wizard.

Comment: Tools->Options->Enviroment->FontsAndColor. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes. But there is no settings for C#

Comment: Fond this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/725446d7-ec5d-4043-b870-9a0e7143cbaa/vs-2012-missing-font-and-color-options-for-xml-files?forum=csharpide I recommend caution